# How to separate a data frame based on a column's range of values with pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, api

This is a bit of weird question, but I have been importing property data from an api in the format of a json file within python. I then use Pandas to convert the json into a dataframe.

I am having trouble manipulating the data within the data frame. My current data is set up as to be formatted like this table.

[image]

Each Property is assigned a name and a property id and address, and there is a record for every unit within a property. Ideally, I would like to create multiple data frames separated by property id, such that it would look like this.

[image]

My only problem here is that due to their being some organization issues, there are about 100 different property ids, and none of the ids are in order. They all have a random number from 1 - 1000.

Is there a way to automatically separate dataframes based on property id by using some sort of unique identifier combined with a for loop ?

I don't really know how to approach the scenario. Thanks!

Comment: Can you just `groupby` Property ID, and generate data frame from each group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
list_of_dataframes = [x for _, x in df.groupby(df['Property Id'].ne(df['Property Id'].shift(1)).cumsum())]
```

Now `list_of_dataframes` is a `list` of dataframes, where each dataframe contains the rows where the `Property Id` was **consecutively** the same. So `Property Id`s `1 1 1 9 9 9 1 1 1` would return **3 dataframes**, one containing the first three 1's, the second containing the next three 9's, and the last containing the last three 1's.

If don't want the groups to be based on the consective order (i.e., you want `1 1 1 9 9 9 1 1 1` to be two dataframes, the first containing all six 1's, and the second containing the three 9's), you can do this:

```
list_of_dataframes = [x for _, x in df.groupby(df['Property Id'])]
```

Comment: I believe this has worked for me using the second line of code you provided. I appreciate your help. Now, originally, after I had created my data frame I used the command output = df.to_csv('test.csv').  Do you know how i would go about creating a csv file for each dataframe in the list?

Comment: @pizzleberry sorry for the inconvenience, but will you please ask a new question about that? You can link it here